# MIPS findmin of array function

Tags: arrays, function, assembly, mips, minimum

Hello I am getting exception 7 [bad data address] for the following findMin number in an array function. The length of the array is already in $a1, and the address of the start of the array is in $a0. I want to have the min in $v0 after all is said and done. **My function works for arrays with 2 elements** but shoots out exception 7 errors when using bigger sized arrays. I am offsetting the array by adding to the address instead of using something like the 4 in 4($a0) offsetting.

Comment: What line is it crashing on?

Comment: I believe it is the lw $t5, 0($a0) in the loop label. The main thing that is throwing me off is that how could it work for an array of size 2 but not greater?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They key here is `add $a0, $a0, $t1`. Consider what that will do in the case of an array with `N` elements: on the second iteration you'll add `1*4`, on the third iteration `2*4`, and so on. So on the third iteration you'd be trying to read from `array + 1*4 + 2*4 == array + 3*4` instead of `array + 2*4`. And on the `N:th` iteration you'd be trying to read from `array + 1*4 + 2*4 + ... + (N-1)*4`.

The `sll + add` before the `lw` should be removed. Updating the address can be done *after* the `lw` with an `addiu $a0, $a0, 4`.

Comment: Thank you so much! So since I wasn't going back to the original start address of the array, I was trying to access a spot in the array which doesn't exist? Would my code have been correct if I used the same starting address each time?

Comment: Just changed the add $a0, $a0, $t1 to add $t6, $a0, $t1 to preserve the $a0 starting address of the array and it works! Thanks again.